# Quickly sum over vector outer products

Tags: matrix

I am trying to do a simple summation over outer products.  I wrote the code as straightforwardly as I could, but perhaps there is a more efficient way to do it.

```
{mat1,mat2} = 
   Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/d9m7mgd4gio78t4/12SeptemberData.nc", 
   {"Datasets",{"matrix1","matrix2"}}];
{sdim,ldim}=Dimensions[mat1];
dim = sdim + ldim;

DM = ConstantArray[0, {dim,dim}];
kcounter=0;
Do[
   If[kcounter != k, Print[k]; kcounter += 1;];
   (*The evaluation seems to take forever, 
     so this just spits out the current value of the k iterator
     so I can keep track of what is going on.*)
   If[b != a && Chop[mat1[[k, a]] mat1[[k, b]]] != 0 ,
      DM += mat1[[k, a]] mat1[[k, b]] Outer[Times, mat2[[a+sdim]], mat2[[b + sdim]]]];

  ,{k, sdim}, {a, ldim}, {b, ldim}];
```

Before I added the term where it checks to make sure the necessary term is not zero, it was taking a lot longer.  But still, I know there are a lot of *Mathematica* functions I don't know about, and if there were a way to speed up this computation that would be fantastic.

Comment: As a side note, you can use [`Monitor[Do[..], k]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Monitor.html) to monitor `k`.

Comment: Are you aware that the first `sdim` rows of your matrix `mat2` are never used anywhere?

Comment: @MichaelE2, that is great to know!

Comment: @bill_s, those rows get used in the next calculation, which is very similar to this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly than it can be reduced to

```
mat3 = mat2[[sdim + 1 ;; -1]];
DM = Transpose[mat3].Transpose[mat1].mat1.mat3;
```

Or in a more efficient way

```
DM = Transpose[#].# &[mat1.mat3];
```

Update:

You can take into account `a!=b` in the following way

```
DM = Transpose[mat3].(# - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[#]) &[Transpose[mat1].mat1].mat3;
```

Comment: This *almost* does it!  If I comment out the `b!=a` part of the `If` statement, then this matches my result exactly, and does it 20,000 times faster.

Comment: Maybe using this won't be too slow: DM=(1 - IdentityMatrix[dim])Transpose[#].#&[mat1.mat3]

Comment: @TimothyWofford Unfortunately it doesn't match the original problem. See my update.

Comment: @JasonCasamir Oh, I missed this condition, see my update!

Comment: @ybeltukov, this is fantastic!  I am always suspicious when I write my code as a multiple summation that it could be done more efficiently as a matrix multiplication. This does really well, and I was trying to push my luck to see if I could do better by compiling it, but I get an error along the lines of `Compiled expression....should be a machine-size integer.` The code I enter is`dmfunc = Compile[{{m1, _Real, 2}, {m2, _Real, 2}, {sdim, _Integer}},
   Module[{mat3},
    mat3 = m2[[sdim + 1 ;; -1]];
    Transpose[mat3].(# - DiagonalMatrix@Diagonal[#]) &[
      Transpose[mat1].mat1].mat3]];`

Comment: @JasonCasamir Matrix multiplications are not needed to be compiled. They are already implemented as fast as possible.